# Where to include socket.io-client and socket.io-stream client side?

Tags: socket.io

I am quite new to javascript and I am following the example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream to attempt to set up a very simple file transfer that automatically just transfers the file as soon as the client connects.

However, I am getting the error:

```
Error: Module name "socket.io-client" has not been loaded yet for context
```

When I remove that line just to see if stream is working either I get:

```
Error: Module name "socket.io-stream" has not been loaded yet for context
```

socket.io-client missing sort of makes sense to me (as I have not included it anywhere in my `<script>` tags). However, the tutorial listed above has no mention of that. The socket.io-stream missing doesn't make sense to me as I followed their advice in the tutorial running

```
cp node_modules/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream.js public/static/js
```

(Where index.html resides in public/) and included the JS file in my index.html

Kind of having a tough time finding answers on this one, any help you can offer is greatly appreciated!

Here is my server side code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80); 
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');
var path = require('path');

io.of('/').on('connection', function(socket) {
  ss(socket).on('write-file', function(stream, data) {
    var filename = path.basename(data.name);
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
  });
});
```

and client side code:

index.html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/socket.io-stream.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/require.js"></script>
<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/client.js"></script>
```

client.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
var stream = ss.createStream();

ss(socket).emit('write-file', stream, { name: 'test.txt' });
fs.createReadStream('test.txt').pipe(stream);
```

Here is a tree directory of my project

```
├── index.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── socket.io
│   ├── socket.io-stream
│   ├── socket.io-client
│   ├──  ... a billion other node modules
└── public
    ├── index.html
    ├── static
    │   ├── glyphicons
    │   ├── js
    │   │   ├── client.js
    │   │   ├── require.js
    │   │   └── socket.io-stream.js
    │   └── style.css
    ├── test.txt
```

Comment: `socket.io.js` is the socket.io client for use in a browser so you should not separately need `socket.io-client.js` in the web page.  `socket.io-client.js` is used on the server-side for client functionality from the server (where the server connects to other socket.io servers).

Comment: Your server-side code does not show any code that would allow the client to have access to `/static/js/socket.io.js` or `/static/js/socket.io-stream.js`.  Node.js does not serve ANY files by default so unless you create routes for those specific files or general purpose routes for a whole directory of files, the browser will just get a 404 (not found) error when it tries to load those `<script>` tags.